# create an HTML button with Onlick that aslo works as a link?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that adds a product to a basket - I would like to make the button when clicked add the product to the basket via the onclick script - then redirect to a page trough an a href link or similar. Is this possible?

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="pl157821buy" class="actionbutton" value="Köp" onclick="buy(this, 157821, null, 'pl157821qty',null, '/ajax/buy')">
```

Comment: Just add `location.href = "url-to-go-to";` in the buy function

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is best practice, but you could use `window.location.assign("/your/other/page")` right after your call to `buy()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location` object like:

```
function buy(...){
   //your current code
   window.location.href = "http://page to be redirected to";
}
```